# Storing utf-8 characters in Oracle with default NLS_CHARACTERSET setting

Tags: character-encoding, oracle11g

So for some legacy reasons we have an Oracle Database with `NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252`. Now we want to store CJK characters into a `VARCHAR2` field. Is this possible, and if so, what do I have to do to implement this?

PS: as the product has been released, changing the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` will be out of the question.

**EDIT**

So far we have come up with an idea like this:
For each CJK character we break it into its UTF-8 byte representations, then store the byte sequence into database. In return, we reorganize them into a CJK character. For example, the Chinese character `中` would be `0xe4, 0xb8, 0xad`, so we store the 3 bytes instead.

However this approach seems not work correctly. If we store Chinese character `华` which is `0xe5, 0x8d, 0x8e` in byte, it becomes `0xe5, 0xbf, 0x8e` in database.

We are using Java language, have no idea if this has any to do with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Not correctly, no.  If the character set of the database is Windows-1252, the only characters you can properly store in a `VARCHAR2` column are those that exist in the Windows-1252 character set.

If the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` is Unicode (generally `AL16UTF16`), you could create an `NVARCHAR2` column and store CJK characters in that new column.  Your application may need code changes in order to support `NVARCHAR2` columns.

Comment: Thank you Justin for your answer. I had added our current approach (not working correctly though) in question, will you please help review that, say, if it's (near) correct way?